# best column type for hashed data in mysql

Tags: mysql, datatypes

In my use case I have a table with a column containing hashed (sha256) IDs. I wonder which data type is better considering that It must be unique and I need to search on it.

The sha algorithm produce a binary stream out of the box. I can transform it hexadecimal or base64 before storing it. I wonder if it is convenient or necessary for my needs

Comment: Double transform `bin --> hex --> b64` is just a waste of resources. Use the fixed-size `BINARY(32)` column for storing the data. It has no collation so no overhead for processing and also it is indexed way better that collated charsets.

Answer (score 5):

If you are starting with hex, use `UNHEX()` when storing and `HEX()` when fetching.  Use `BINARY(32)` for the datatype.  This occupies a constant 32 bytes.

If you are starting with binary, then be careful when escaping to store/load.  Probably best to do a double convert each way.

Be sure to have lots of RAM.  Once the index becomes bigger than the buffer_pool, the system will slow down because of the randomness of sha256 (or any other hash or uuid).

If you go with Base64, then use `CHAR(43) COLLATE ascii_bin`, which will be a constant 43 bytes, and will be case-sensitive.

256 is gross overkill.  If you have about 2^85 entries, there is only one chance in 2^85 of having *any* hash collisions.  For a mere MD5, those numbers are 9 trillion.

Answer (score 1):

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979100/how-to-store-binary-data-in-mysql

The recommendation would be to store it as a Base64 encoded string.

> Short pieces of binary data, such as password hashes, work very well
>   by simply base64-encoding them and storing the resulting string as a
>   VARCHAR

Comment: as sha256 is fixed length why not using CHAR? CHAR(44) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240973/how-long-is-the-sha256-hash#answer-28869026)?

Comment: @masciugo `BINARY(32)` even better!

Comment: @Kondybas thank you but I may need to do some manual searches/checks on the DB so, if there are not so many drawbacks, I would prefer using readable CHARs

Comment: @masciugo You can convert the values bin->char and char->bin right in the query and keep the table in the most efficient and compact representation. Hashing is intended to speed up the search so it would be reasonable to keep it as fast as possible.